# Python-Turtle Fill issues

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fill

I have been playing around with Turtle and, while the shapes fill in, I get strange extras outside of the shape.

This is my code. I'm using Windows 11 Notepad with Terminal to view results.

I have tried inserting a `turtle.penup()` right before the `turtle.end_fill()`, and directly after, but the image remains the same.

When I run the application I get the desired image but with a diagonal smudge towards the top left corner:

```
Code:  Draws the Youtube Symbol

#Youtube Symbol with Turtle Python

#600x1000 box with a white "Play" button

import turtle

t = turtle

t.speed(10)

t.bgcolor("white")
t.fillcolor("red")
t.begin_fill()
    #Starts on the down stroke L. side
t.penup()
t.color('red')
t.pensize(75)
t.setpos(-500, 300)
t.right(90)
t.pendown()
t.fd(600)

#Bottom
t.left(90)
t.fd(1000)

#Right Side
t.left(90)
t.fd(600)

#top
t.left(90)
t.fd(1000)

t.end_fill()

#White play button
t.fillcolor('white')
t.begin_fill()
t.penup()
t.pensize(75)
t.color('white')
t.setpos(-200, 200)
t.pendown()
t.left(90)
t.fd(400)
t.left(110)
t.fd(550)
t.left(137)
t.fd(550)
t.end_fill()
t.penup()

t.done()
```

Unfortunately I can not share a picture of my issue at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest fix is to move this block of statements:

```
t.penup()
t.pensize(75)
t.color('white')
t.setpos(-200, 200)
t.pendown()
t.left(90)
```

to *before* the `t.begin_fill()` instead of after.  Otherwise, the turtle's position from the previous drawing becomes part of the fill area.

A rework of your code to address the above and lesser issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1200, 800)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fast')
turtle.pensize(75)

# Red 600x1000 box
turtle.setheading(270)
turtle.color("red")
turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(-500, 300)
turtle.pendown()

turtle.begin_fill()

for _ in range(2):
    turtle.forward(600)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(1000)
    turtle.left(90)

turtle.end_fill()

# White play button
turtle.color('white')

turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(-200, 200)
turtle.pendown()

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.forward(400)
turtle.left(110)
turtle.forward(550)
turtle.left(137.7)
turtle.forward(550)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```